# Why would ADO.Net Entity Data Model Designer fails to open my EDMX file?

Tags: ado.net, system.data.sqlite, edmx

When trying to open the designer VS2010 complains that ...
Cannot load 'C:...\Model.edmx': Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
Now the thing is that I had previously created this database first model and the code successfully runs and does access the DataBase. I'm using SQLite v1.0.76.0 which I've installed and added to my References and have modified my App.Config as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.76.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EDSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\EDS.db&quot;;foreign keys=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I am at a loss as to what the issue might be ... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the SQLite .Net Provider resolved the issue.

Comment: I don't think I had properly followed the installation instructions in http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/readme.htm